# Change context menu text based on which element is clicked

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I’ve built a Chrome extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/omnibear/cjieakdeocmiimmphkfhdfbihhncoocn). It adds an item to the context menu, so the user can right-click an element on the page and reply to the associated “entry” on their blog.

My problem is, whether or not I can find an “entry” depends on where they click, and involves traversing up the DOM tree. I have the code in place that highlights the entry when the `contextmenu` event is fired, but this is too late to update the text in the context menu. Is there a way to update the context menu text dynamically as it is opened?

(e.g., I would like it to say “Reply to page” if no entry is found, or “Reply to tweet” if a tweet is found)

Comment: [Creating dynamic context menu in Chrome Extension is failing](//stackoverflow.com/a/13673942) - adjust the content script part to your needs.

Comment: Yeah, I know *how* to update the context menu, it's more a question of timing, because the contextmenu event is too late. Maybe I need to try doing it in the mousedown or click event. Will those resolve before the contextmenu event?

Comment: Ah, yes, `mousedown` is needed. I should have added a link to [chrome extension context menus, how to display a menu item only when there is no selection?](//stackoverflow.com/a/6388261). There was a more complete answer, but I can't find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in a Chrome extension/Firefox WebExtension, there is no way to have your JavaScript make dynamic changes to the context menu *at the time the context menu opens*. The only thing that dynamically changes *at the time the context menu opens* is: if you have added a context menu item that has the `selection` context for its [ContextType](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#type-ContextType), then you can [specify `%s` in the `title`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#property-createProperties-title), which will be replaced with the current selection.

## Change the context menu before it begins to open

### Mouse events

To do what you desire, you need to make the changes to the context menu prior to the beginning of the context menu being opened. This can be accomplished by having a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) that listens to the [`mouseup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseup) event. You may have to end up using the [`mousedown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousedown) event, or one or more of the [`mouseenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter)/[`mouseleave`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseleave)/[`mouseover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover)/[`mouseout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseout) events. If you do need to use `mousedown`, once that event fires you should then start listening to some of the `mouseenter`/`mouseleave`/`mouseover`/`mouseout` events to tell when the element the mouse is over changes, or just assume the user releases the button on the same element on which they pressed it down.

If the `mouseup`/`mousedown` event is for `button=2`, then you will need to [message your background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to change the context menu with [`contextMenus.update()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#method-update). There are multiple asynchronous portions of this process. This may make for various race conditions, and may necessitate using events which give you earlier notification than `mouseup` (e.g. `mousedown`, `mouseenter`/`mouseleave`/`mouseover`/`mouseout`).

What events you need to watch for may be operating system/platform/windowing system dependent. You will need to test to determine what is needed in each environment you plan to support.

### Keyboard events

The context menu can also be opened using a few keyboard sequences. You will need to listen for and perform the same messaging as is needed for mouse events. You will need to determine what these events are in all operating systems/platforms/windowing systems which you are supporting.

#### Linux

On Linux it appears to [vary at least based on platform](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167088/keyboard-shortcut-equivalent-to-right-clicking).

#### OSX

On OSX, it appears that a [keyboard shortcut is only available if enabled](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/136634/keyboard-shortcut-to-open-context-menu).

#### Windows

On Windows, the keyboard shortcuts to open the context menu are:

**Context Menu key**

You will need to detect the following event sequence:

```
keydown { target: <body>, key: "ContextMenu", charCode: 0, keyCode: 93 }
keypress { target: <body>, key: "ContextMenu", charCode: 0, keyCode: 93 }
keyup { target: <body>, key: "ContextMenu", charCode: 0, keyCode: 93 }
```

The context menu does not open until around the same time the `keyup` event fires. I did not test to see if the `keyup` happens early enough for you to make changes to the context menu prior to it opening.

**Keyboard combination: <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F10</kbd>**

You will need to detect the following event sequence:

```
keydown Shift { target: <body>, key: "Shift", charCode: 0, keyCode: 16, shiftKey: true }
keydown Shift { target: <body>, key: "F10", charCode: 0, keyCode: 121, shiftKey: true }
keypress Shift { target: <body>, key: "F10", charCode: 0, keyCode: 121, shiftKey: true }
```

In this case, the context menu opens at around the same time as the shifted <kbd>F10</kbd> `keydown`/`keypress` events fire. No `keyup` event fires for this keyboard sequence.