# Conditionally enable contextMenus based on Tab URL

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

`contextMenus` has a `enabled` property which can be set to true or false.

`contextMenus.update()` can be used to update the properties.

I would like to enable or disable a contextmenu (one of a few contextmenus) based on conditions.

`contextMenus.onClicked.addListener()` is fired after the contextmenu is shown so there is no point to use update to change the `enabled` property (based on tab URL).

Is there a way to change the `enabled` property before it is shown? (like `popupshowing` event was in Firefox)

**Update:**

> **Note:** At this point I am looking for any method of controlling the contextmenu (based on Tab URL) BEFORE it is displayed. The case listed here is just one
>   example of a situation where such method would be needed.

I am looking for a direct method and not a hack by listening to all mouse events. Furthermore, using a series of asynchronous functions will have unpredictable results.

The actual `contexts` in this case is `tab` (which is only supported by Firefox 53.*+).
I am not aware of any mouse event listener for it for this purpose.

Injecting scripts into the context is the heart of the problem.

Firefox (& Chrome) by design prevent script injection into certain locations eg: addons.mozilla.org, about:* or Chrome Web Store; etc.

The problem is more pronounced on Firefox due to unavailability of a number of APIs.
(You can read my comments: [WebExtension content script not working on mozilla.org sites](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1310082))

At the moment, I am forced to run a series of functions to check if the page is blocked or not, after action has been initiated from the contextmenu.

I was looking for a way to **disable** some of the extensions contextmenu items based on the URL of the tab. In other words, disable few of the extension's contextmenu items on addons.mozilla.org

There are some tab listeners but they don't seem to suit the purpose ie (`tabs.onCreated`: Fired when a tab is created. Note that the tab's URL may not be set at the time this event fired.)

PS. While I am working on a Firefox extension, since Firefox & Chrome share the similar API and the `enable` property is used by both, the question has been tagged with both browsers. I have re-ordered the tags to list Firefox as its primary target.
PS2. Stack Overflow puts it under Chrome Extension regardless, so I have removed the Chrome reference tag.
PS3. Voting to close a question prematurely and without knowing all the facts is rather counterproductive.

Comment: Send a message to the background page from your content script on `mousedown` event like e.g. [chrome extension context menus, how to display a menu item only when there is no selection?](//stackoverflow.com/a/6388261). You may also want to handle `keydown` event to catch `Apps` and `Shift-F10` keys (on Windows at least).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change context menu text based on which element is clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563886/change-context-menu-text-based-on-which-element-is-clicked)

Comment: Hmmm.. Actually, even though it's tagged `google-chrome-extension`, not `firefox-webextentions`, the answer wOxxOm linked to: [chrome extension context menus, how to display a menu item only when there is no selection?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6382467) is a better answer (has code rather than just a description of what you would need to do). Thus, it is probably a better duplicate-target. Neither answer currently discusses catching the various keyboard events which open the context menu.

Comment: Voting to close a question is precisely what *should* be done when all the facts needed to provide an answer are not in the question. That is *definitely* one of the explicit reasons for closing a question. If the OP adds enough info, it can be reopened. The info you added to the question indicates it should have been voted-to-close because it was "Unclear what you're asking", instead of a duplicate. However, from the version which you first posted, assuming that it was a duplicate of the linked questions was reasonable. Communication requires 2+ people, all share responsibility.

Comment: While you can listen to `tabs` and `webNavigation` events to see changes in tab URLs, nothing is really going to accomplish what you appear to desire. The `tab` context is for all tab UI elements, not just the currently active tab. Changing the `tab` context menu to reflect what is possible for the current active tab will leave the user stranded when they click on the context menu for a completely different non-active tab that has a different URL.

Comment: Thank you @Makyen .. The original post clearly indicated 'enable based on tab URL'. The examples in other questions dealt with the element in page content which is a TOTALLY different issue. It also specifically asked about the property of `enabled`. None of the examples related to the questions that were asked. That is the reason I provided additional information. I was under the impression that the original post had sufficient info.

Comment: Please clarify: Are you wanting to change the context menu for each tab based on the URL for that tab? Or, are you wanting to change the context menu for *all tabs* based on the URL for the active tab in the current window?

Comment: That is a good question and both possibilities have their own uses. At this point I am looking for any method of controlling the contextmenu BEFORE it is displayed. The case in the initial post is just one example of a situation where such method would be needed.

Comment: @erosman, [Please use `@Makyen` to notify me of comments directed to me. I only saw your most recent comment because I happened to come back to the question.]  What you want does not exist. It probably should exist (depending on your point of view). Please [file a bug on Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/) as a tracking bug/request for enhancement to create a pre-shown callback for context menus (e.g. perhaps similar to the Add-on SDK [`PredicateContext`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/context-menu#Declarative_contexts)).