# OnClicked function for a top-level item in a multi-level context menu?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am writing a WebExtensions Firefox/Chrome addon that adds one context menu item with a number of submenu items. The problem is that the submenu items need to be generated dynamically, based on the current page. I thought that I would just add an onClicked function to the top-level item, which would then generate the submenu. But this doesn't seem to work: when the mouse is hovered over the top-level item, the submenu is expanded without the onClicked function being called.

Is there an alternative way of implementing what I want to do?

```js
// Top-level item
browser.contextMenus.create({
 id: "menu_top",
 type: "normal",
 title: "My Extension",
 contexts: ["all"],
 onclick: buildMenu
})
// Permanent submenu item
browser.contextMenus.create({
 id: "checkbox",
 parentId: "menu_top",
 type: "checkbox",
 title: "Check",
 checked: isChecked,
 contexts: ["all"],
 onclick: function() {
  isChecked = !isChecked
 }
})
// Generate submenu items - never called
function buildMenu(onClickData) {
 // Add more submenu items
}
```

Comment: You have to build the entire menu before it's shown. The only reliable method I know is to have a content script that listens to `mousedown` and checks if the button is `2` (also `keydown` and `Apps` or `Shift-F10` keys), sends a message to the background/event page, the latter builds the menu. There are several answers on SO that elaborate on the topic.

Comment: Duplicates: [Change context menu text based on which element is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42563886) and [chrome extension context menus, how to display a menu item only when there is no selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6382467)

Comment: To provide a good answer, or give better suggestions, we need to know *exactly* what you mean by "generated dynamically, based on the current page."

Comment: Thanks, @wOxxOm. I found a different solution that does not require generating the menu just before it is opened, but I'll keep this information in mind for the future. Odd that there isn't an event for context menu opening.